# Footer links Static Block Messed up

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

I was trying to change the footer links which I have done countless times but for some reason this has now messed up on the layout of the footers.

[image]

Here is what I have in the Information block:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="{{store url='aboutus/'}}">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{store url='catalogsearch/term/popular/'}}">Search Terms</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{store url='terms-and-conditions/'}}">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
    <li><a href="Our History" href="{{store url='history/'}}">Our History</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{store url='news/'}}">Our Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{store url='contact-us/'}}">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{store url='directdelivery/'}}">Manufacturers Direct Delivery</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{store url='laura-ashley/'}}">Laura Ashley Collection</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{store url='montrosebathroomplannerguide/'}}">Montrose Bathroom Design Guide</a></li>
    <li class=" last"><a href="{{store url='catalog/seo_sitemap/category/'}}">Site Map</a></li>
</ul>
```

I really need a little help on this.

This is the code from the footer.phtml file

```
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('brands') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('aw_blog_footer') ?>
<div class="footer-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="footer">
                      <p id="back-top"><a href="#top"><span></span></a> </p>
                      <div class="footer-cols-wrapper">
        <div class="footer-col">            
         <div class="f_block">
          <h4><?php echo $this->__('Our Store') ?></h4>
          <div class="footer-col-content">
           <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_about') ?>
          </div>
         </div>
         <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer.newsletter') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-col">            
         <div class="f_block foot_space1">
          <h4><?php echo $this->__('Information') ?></h4>
          <div class="footer-col-content">
           <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cms_footer_links_static') ?>
           <?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_links') ?>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="f_block">
          <h4><?php echo $this->__('Store Information') ?></h4>
          <div class="footer-col-content">
           <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_information') ?>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_list') ?>
        <div class="footer-col last">
        <!--<div class="f_block">
          <h4><?php echo $this->__('Facebook') ?></h4>
          <div class="footer-col-content">
           <div class="facebook_block">
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('tm/facebook/facebook_like.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
           </div>
          </div> 
         </div>-->
         <div class="f_block">
          <h4><?php echo $this->__('Follow us') ?></h4>
          <div class="footer-col-content">
           <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('socials') ?>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
                      </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="bottom_block">
                    <address><?php echo $this->getCopyright() ?></address>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('paypal.partner.right.logo'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_switcher') ?>
                    <?php $current_page = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName(); 
                        if ($current_page == 'cms'):
                        endif;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What edits do I need to make guys?

Comment: I check it is design issue.  set .footer .footer-col { width:100% }
also div are not correct. please set proper block

Comment: remove heights and .footer .footer-col{width: 100%} instead 25% http://prntscr.com/fr0ef0

Comment: I looked at your screenshot and usually its set as columns so "Our Store" and the "subscribe" would be in the left hand column, 2nd column would hold "information" & underneath would be the "Contact us" then in the 3rd column would be the "Socials". How could i set it back to the original design?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have remove some CSS class, and you have some issue in your code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="{{store url='aboutus'}}">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{store url='catalogsearch/term/popular'}}">Search Terms</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{store url='terms-and-conditions'}}">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{store url='history'}}">Our History</a></li><!--You have a error here-->
    <li><a href="{{store url='news'}}">Our Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{store url='contact-us'}}">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{store url='directdelivery'}}">Manufacturers Direct Delivery</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{store url='laura-ashley'}}">Laura Ashley Collection</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{store url='montrosebathroomplannerguide'}}">Montrose Bathroom Design Guide</a></li>
    <li class=" last"><a href="{{store url='catalog/seo_sitemap/category'}}">Site Map</a></li>
</ul>
```